# Mongo Index strategy for similar indexes

Tags: mongodb

I have the following Schema:

```
{
  A: String,
  B: String,
  C: String,
  D: String,
}
```

If I have a where filter with A, B, C, and A, B, D, should I:

index (A, B, C) and (A, B, D)

### OR

index (A, B), and separately (C) and (D)?

### OR

index (A, B, C, D)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index (A, B, C) and (A, B, D)

---

index (A, B), and separately (C) and (D) requires index intersection which has so many conditions to meet that it almost never happens in the wild.

index (A, B, C, D) will work perfectly for (A, B, C) queries and only as good as index (A, B) alone for (A, B, D) queries.

It's very well documented in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes